# Hierarchical SQL Query WITH parent child items

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, postgresql

```
Category (id, name,        parent_id);
          1   Electronics  NULL
          2   Computers    1
          3   Notebooks    2
          4   Desktops     2

Products (id, name,      category_id);
          1   NotebookX  3
          2   NotebookY  3
          3   NotebookZ  3
          4   DesktopX   2
          5   DesktopY   2
```

1- I want to select parent category list of a specified category.

2- I want to select product list of a category ans sub categories.

```
Select category 1 should return 5 products. 
          1   NotebookX  3
          2   NotebookY  3
          3   NotebookZ  3
          4   DesktopX   2
          5   DesktopY   2
    Select category 2 should return 5 products. 
          1   NotebookX  3
          2   NotebookY  3
          3   NotebookZ  3
          4   DesktopX   2
          5   DesktopY   2
    Select category 3 should return 3 products. 
          1   NotebookX  3
          2   NotebookY  3
          3   NotebookZ  3
    Select category 4 should return 2 products.
          4   DesktopX   2
          5   DesktopY   2
```

I am new at sql recursive queries so could not create.

```
WITH RECURSIVE graph AS (
    SELECT id, name
    FROM category
    WHERE parent_id IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT v.id, v.name
    FROM category as v
    JOIN graph r on v.parent_id = r.id
    ????????????
    ????????????
)
SELECT id, name FROM graph;
```

(I am using postgreql. But you can write any database.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give it a try (**SQL Server** solution):

```
DECLARE @category int = 3

;WITH rec AS (
SELECT *
FROM Category c
WHERE c.id = @category
UNION ALL
SELECT c.*
FROM rec r
INNER JOIN Category c
    ON c.parent_id = r.id
)

SELECT p.*
FROM Products p
INNER JOIN rec r
    ON r.id = p.category_id
```

At first we get a category we choose. Than we select from `Category` all its children in a recursive part. After that we got in `rec` all sub categories. Than we join `Products` with categories from `rec`.

**EDIT#1**

You can put `rec` results into temp table and then use them:

```
SELECT *
INTO #rec
FROM rec

SELECT p.*
FROM Products p
INNER JOIN #rec r
    ON r.id = p.category_id

SELECT *
FROM #rec

DROP TABLE #rec
```

Output for `@category=3`:

```
id          name      category_id
----------- --------- -----------
1           NotebookX 3
2           NotebookY 3
3           NotebookZ 3

(3 row(s) affected)

id          name        parent_id
----------- ----------- -----------
3           Notebooks   2

(1 row(s) affected)
```

**EDIT#2**

To get descendants:

```
DECLARE @category int = 2

;WITH rec AS (
SELECT *
FROM Category c
WHERE c.id = @category
UNION ALL
SELECT c.*
FROM rec r
INNER JOIN Category c
    ON c.id = r.parent_id
)

SELECT *
FROM rec
```

Output:

```
id  name        parent_id
2   Computers   1
1   Electronics NULL
```

For parents:

```
DECLARE @category int = 2

;WITH rec AS (
SELECT *
FROM Category c
WHERE c.id = @category
UNION ALL
SELECT c.*
FROM rec r
INNER JOIN Category c
    ON c.parent_id = r.id
)
```

Output:

```
id  name        parent_id
2   Computers   1
3   Notebooks   2
4   Desktops    2
```

Comment: This works well, but how can I list parent and descendants of a category?

Comment: Change last select to `SELECT * FROM rec` it will list category's you choose with descendants.

Comment: I expand my answer. Please, take a look.

Comment: I want to list only parents of a category not products. Example for Computers category has 1 parents(Electronics) and has 2 descendants (Notebooks, Desktops). I wnat to create two sql query for these lists. One of them wil list descendants and other will be list parents of a category.

Comment: Well, it is not what written in your question... F.e. *Select category 1 should return 5 products...* - and the first query from my example do this thing. If you need to get parents and descendants in two separate lists - you can use the same query but use `ON c.id = r.parent_id` to show parents of category you have chosen. I add this to my answer (see EDIT#2)